# Problema para actualizar los datos de PHP a phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, update

Disculpad si me estoy saltando el protocolo pero esta vez no encuentro la llave en Stack. Es mi primer mensaje en este foro para pedir ayuda.

Básicamente lo que tengo que hacer es actualizar la tabla "usuarios" de bbdd de phpmyadmin. Algún paso debo omitir al escribir el código. No me da ningún error, pero tampoco se actualiza.
Me imprime por pantalla "Usuario actualizado correctamente".
He buscado la solución en algún post parecido pero no llego a entender bien el funcionamiento y no logro resolverlo, os agradezco la ayuda que me podáis dar
Espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano. Os adjunto el código:
update.php

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';

if(isset($_GET['upd'])) $id = $_GET['upd'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($res > 0){
    $data = $stmt->fetch();
}

?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="sass/users.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
<body>

<div class="container_form">
<div><h1>Actualizar usuario</h1></div>
<form action='upd.php' method="post">
<table class='user_table'>
        <tr>
                
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Rol</th>
            <!-- <th>Operacion</th> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name='id' value="<?**=** $data['id']?>">
        <td><input type="text" name='nombre' placeholder='nombre' value="<?= $data['nombre']?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='apellido' placeholder='apellido' value="<?= $data['apellido']?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email' value="<?= $data['email']?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='id_roles' placeholder='Rol' value="<?= $data['id_roles'] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type=submit name='Actualizar'></td>
        </tr>
    
    
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

upd.php

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['Actualizar'])){
if (!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['id_roles'])){
    
    // $id = $_POST['id'];
    // $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    // $email = $_POST['email'];
    // $id_roles = $_POST['id_roles'];

    $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET id = :id , nombre = :nombre , **apellido = :apellido**, email = :email , id_roles = :id_roles WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $_POST['nombre']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":apellido", $_POST['apellido']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_roles", $_POST['id_roles']);

    //DA ERROR
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Usuario actualizado correctamente");</script>';
        // header("location:users.php");
    }else{
        echo "Complete todos los campos";
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Con la actualización, me sigue dando fallo en apellido.

Comment: Me auto-resuelvo: me faltaba apellido = :apellido en la consulta Es increible, es venir aquí y veo las cosas :)

Comment: Debería borrar el post?? Gracias!

Comment: En tu código hay prácticas no recomendadas de todos modos.

Comment: Seguro, estoy empezando en esto! dime cuales @A.Cedano

Comment: El Manual de PHP dice con toda claridad que no deberías confiar en `rowCount()` para consultas `SELECT`, para saber con toda certeza si hay datos en una consulta, tienes dos opciones: 1. Ejecutar una consulta SELECT COUNT(*) ... 2. Leer los datos con uno de los métodos `fetch` y comprobar esos datos. En cambio en el `UPDATE`  sí deberías verificar con `rowCount()`  porque una consulta UPDATE puede no fallar, pero puedo no haber actualizado nada, por ejemplo, si mandas a actualizar con todos los datos iguales a los que ya existen, la instrucción no da error, pero actualiza 0 filas.

Comment: Luego le echo un ojo! Muchas gracias por el consejo @A.Cedano

Comment: De nada. Lo puedes leer luego en el [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php): *Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.* Y por definición: *rowCount devuelve el nº de filas afectadas por la última sentencia DELETE, INSERT, o UPDATE ejecutada por el correspondiente objeto PDOStatement.*

Comment: @HéctorGonzálezPereda respondiendo a tu pregunta de si deberías borrar el post, creería que no. Lo que no está bien es editar la pregunta y corregir el error allí, sino que deberías autoresponder la pregunta (agregando una respuesta) y seleccionandolá como respuesta aceptada, así la pregunta queda marcada como respondida.